# I can't send Confirm Email on SendGrid

Tags: c#

I'm working on .Net Core Mvc. I'm trying to take confirm email on Sendgrid. I don't want to use Smtp.When I'm on register form I created account but I can't take Confirm Email.

```
 [HttpPost]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        var user = new ApplicationUser
        {
            UserName = model.Username,
            Email = model.Email,
            FullName = model.FullName
        };

        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            // generate token
            var code =await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
            var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail","Account",new
            {
               UserId=user.Id,
               token=code
            });

            // send email
            await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(model.Email, "Confirm your Email",
                $"If you want to confirm your email click on <a href='http://localhost:52803/{callbackUrl}'>link.</a>");

            return RedirectToAction("Login","Account");
        }


        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Bilinmeyen hata oluştu lütfen tekrar deneyiniz.");
        return View(model);
    }
```

and here's my EmailSenderService

```
public class EmailSender:IEmailSender
{
    private const string SendGridKey = "***";
  
    public Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string htmlMessage)
    {
        return Execute(SendGridKey, subject, htmlMessage, email);
    }

    private Task Execute(string sendGridKey, string subject, string htmlMessage, string email)
    {
        var client = new SendGridClient(sendGridKey);

        var msg = new SendGridMessage()
        {
            From = new EmailAddress("info@shopapp.com", "Shop App"),
            Subject = subject,
            PlainTextContent = htmlMessage,
            HtmlContent = htmlMessage
        };

        msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress(email));
        return client.SendEmailAsync(msg);


    }
}
```

I added this to my Startup: `services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();`
When I checked my email, I couldn't see confirm message. What's my problem?

Comment: Try putting a break point on `return client.SendEmailAsync(msg);` and then step over it (F10) and check, if there are any errors

Comment: In your `SendGridClient` are you sure you have the right SMTP client settings?

Comment: I fixed guys.SendGrind doesnt work.I changed my email service.I created Smtp and its okay now. Thanks for answers.